# Matching a <= BinaryOperator using Clang's ASTvisitor

Tags: compiler-construction, clang, abstract-syntax-tree, semantics, visitor-pattern

I have the following `AST` and I'd like to visit `<=` using BinaryOperator visitor:

```
| |   `-ForStmt 0xfcb1fd8 <line:7:2, line:14:2>
| |     |-DeclStmt 0xfcb1680 <line:7:7, col:20>
| |     | `-VarDecl 0xfcb15e8 <col:7, col:19> col:17 used i 'uint16_t':'unsigned short' cinit
| |     |   `-ImplicitCastExpr 0xfcb1668 <col:19> 'uint16_t':'unsigned short' <IntegralCast>
| |     |     `-IntegerLiteral 0xfcb1648 <col:19> 'int' 0
| |     |-BinaryOperator 0xfcb1a28 <col:22, col:55> 'bool' '<='
| |     | |-ImplicitCastExpr 0xfcb19f8 <col:22> 'int' <IntegralCast>
```

[BinaryOperator](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1BinaryOperator.html) is inherited from `Expr::BinaryOperator`, I can't quite figure out how to traverse down from an `Expr *E` to a `BinaryOperator *BO`:

```
static bool vectorLoopConditionVisitor(Sema &S, BinaryOperator *BO){

    if (!BO){
    // error
      }
   if (!BO->isAssignmentOp() && //need a condition to match with "<=" ){  
      // error
    }


  return false;
}

 static bool vectorLoopVisitor(Sema &S, Stmt *St, uint32_t Depth) {
    ForStmt *Fst = dyn_cast<ForStmt>(St);

    // ...
    vectorLoopConditionVisitor(S, dyn_cast<BinaryOperator>(Fst->getCond())); 
    // this is most certainly wrong as it returns a null pointer and segfault
    //...
    vectorLoopBodyVisitor(S, Fst->getBody(), Depth);

    return false;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please expand the code a bit more? How do you construct the visitor and how do you traverse the code?

The following visitor should do the job for you:

```
class BinaryVisitor : public clang::RecursiveASTVisitor<BinaryVisitor> {
public:
  bool VisitBinaryOperator(clang::BinaryOperator *binaryOperator) {
    if (binaryOperator->getOpcode() != clang::BinaryOperator::Opcode::BO_LE) {
      return true;
    }

    // Handle the '<=' matching here

    return true;
  }
};

/// ...
BinaryVisitor visitor;
visitor.TraverseDecl(someDecl);
```

This visitor will check every `BinaryOperaror` and will skip anything that is not "less than" (`clang::BinaryOperator::Opcode::BO_LE`).

Comment: Thanks Alex. How do I check when my dyn_cast<class>(parent) returns null? Not all the classes have `IgnoreImpCasts()` and many times I had face segfault which was caused by a nullptrl. E.g., the dyn_cast at `vectorLoopConditionVisitor(S, dyn_cast<BinaryOperator>(Fst->getCond()))` sine I wanted to pass the fundtion `BO` instead of an `Expr`

Comment: dyn_cast returns either a valid pointer or null pointer, so simply checking `if (dyn_cast<BinaryOperator>(something))` should do the job.

Comment: sorry but could you let me know if my Binary operator `RHS` had a builtin function `CallExpr  -> ImplicitCastExpr -> DeclRefExpr` of name `get_loop_b32(var)`. Can I still match it going down this path? I don't seem to do so

Comment: would appreacite your thoughts on this question of mine: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64050621/matching-the-argument-passed-to-a-function-in-a-forstmts-cond-using-clang-ast-v